# How to read multiple tables as a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

While converting an old VB program to a .NET program, the project manager has decided that we need to have a separate tables for the old (vb) Data and the new (.NET) data.

this is where it kinda gets confusing. In order for the .net version to backwards compatible, We need the .NET version to read from both the .Net tables and the old VB tables.

is there some way to have my sql statement read from both tables and treat them as if they a single table?

**example:**

**VB Table:**

Johan Bach

Ludwig Beethoven

**.NET Table:**

Wolfgang Motzart

Johannes Brahms

**SQL will pull this:**

Johan Bach

Ludwig Beethoven

Wolfgang Motzart

Johannes Brahms

Comment: You could use a view that does a `UNION` over both tables that is used by the .Net program

Comment: each name in the above example represents a row in the table.

Comment: You could create a view on top of both tables, with union for example. You could read from it andveven insert (with insert instead). At the point you want to drop this behavior, you could simply change the view or rename the table - without affecting the code.

Comment: a UNION query is likely to be best then. Maybe implemented as a view.

Comment: I am using TSQL i think. going to go look up UNION real quick.

Comment: Union done what I needed it to. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT FullName FROM .NETtable
UNION
SELECT FullName FROM VBtable
ORDER BY FullName;
```

Try this, it should do what you need. I don't know the names of your attributes, just replace them accordingly.

Comment: Just note that `UNION` will be slower and remove true duplicates whereas `UNION ALL` won't. It depends on what data is needed.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose UNION or UNION ALL would be what you are looking for.

Your boss is wrong about separating the tables. You should bring it all under one table and have a legacy property in its own column, for instance "V" as in VB and "N" as in .Net.

With two tables you have two sets of identity columns which will compete with one another and most of your queries will be overly complicated, unless you use a view to perform a UNION, which would then make you wonder why not have it all in one table.

Comment: Having a single table is definitely the better choice. Most probably together with a view that returns only rows intended for the VB program.